# How create multiple faces in a pattern

Tags: faces, edges

I have 2 edge loops, and I want to create faces between them.

I have tried several options like Bridge Edge loops, Make Faces and Convex Hull, but none of these gave me result as I wanted. Please see below image
[image]

The actual result I want is like this-
[image]

Please tell me any solution to do this.

Comment: I have solved using bridge edge loops, the problem was I have selected extra unnecessary edges.

Comment: Glad you figured it out—you should [answer your own question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), then, for other people that happen by.